# Swift Package Manager Public Headers with Complicated Layouts

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager, swift-package, module-map

I have a sample Swift Package Manager package (let's call it `TestPackage`), that is structured in the following way:

```
TestPackage/
  Sources/
    TestPackage/
      Services/
        Services.h
        Services.m
      TestPackageUI/
        UIComponent1.h
        UIComponent1.m
        UIComponent2.h
        UIComponent2.m
      include/
        TestPackage.h (umbrella header)
```

The contents of my `TestPackage.h` look something like this:

```objectivec
/// Umbrella header

/// Services
#import "Services.h" // (or "Services/Services.h")

/// TestPackageUI
#import "Component1.h" // (or "TestPackageUI/Component1.h")
#import "Component2.h" // (or "TestPackageUI/Component2.h")
```

What I want is that users of this package can do import this package into objc/swift and use the Services and TestPackageUI. They could do something such as:

Objective-C:

```objectivec
@import TestPackage;
/// or
#import <TestPackage.h>
```

Swift:

```swift
import TestPackage
```

The SPM [Usage documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md) says:

> In case of complicated include layouts or headers that are not compatible with modules, a custom module.modulemap can be provided in the include directory.

So I added a `module.modulemap` in the `include` directory with the following content:

```
module TestPackage {
  header "TestPackage.h"
  export *
}
```

But when I try to use this package, the umbrella header `TestPackage.h` cannot find the header files it includes. Note that these sub-directories are added as headerSearchPaths in the C Settings of the target. I would like to maintain the same project structure. Can anyone help with the correct way to write a `modulemap` that works with this layout? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Package's `Target` have `publicHeadersPath` property. Please use it. Please stop editing module maps. Generation of correct module maps is SPM responsibility.

Comment: I don’t see how editing that property helps with my problem. All I can do with that is change the directory where my public headers are placed—in other words, some directory other than include. I also don’t want my implementation files to be made public. Furthermore, the SPM usage guidelines advises that you to create a custom module map if you have complicated layouts, so why is it that you recommend I don’t?

Comment: Put implementation files into other folder and they will not be public, doesn't need to create complicated layout.

Comment: That is what I want to avoid doing, hence why I want to get it working with the current layout.

Comment: @B.Morfe Were u able to solve this?